# Intl.dateTimeFormatDate outputs an extra dot for German locale

Tags: javascript, internationalization

I'm using the [Internationalization API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat) to format dates. In particular, I want to display just the day and month part, using German format:

```js
var now = new Date();
var dayMonthFormat = { month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' };
var formatter = Intl.DateTimeFormat('de-DE', dayMonthFormat);
console.log(formatter.format(now));
```

The code above outputs using the format **dd.MM.**

Is the extra dot at the end intentional?

Comment: Yes, this is the way a date is displayed in Germany. i.e.: `01.11.` for today.

Comment: Do you know of any documentation about that? I've found examples of different date formats but not this one. Thanks

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: The german date format is defined in DIN 5008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both day and month are considered ordinals in Germany. That's why they are followed by a dot. So the dot after the MM is normal and required.

['The use of a dot as a separator matches the convention of pronouncing the day and the month as an ordinal number, because ordinal numbers are written in German followed by a dot.'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_Europe#Austria.2C_Germany.2C_Switzerland)

You might want to look up DIN 5008 and (DIN stands for German Institute for Norming). They regularly update the norms for typeset and 5008 has been updated quite a few times in recent years.